# ReadFile on volume fails with ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER after FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO

Tags: winapi, readfile

I'm reading a volume (logical drive) with `ReadFile`. I'm using `DeviceIoContro`l with `FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO` code, because I want to have access to all (including the last) bytes and had an issue trying to read last 512 bytes (`ReadFile` successed, but reported 0 bytes read) and saw advice to use it. Unfortunately, `ReadFile` fails being called after that `DeviceIoControl` called.
In code it looks like this (all success checks are omitted for the brevity):

```
    HANDLE fd;
    DWORD junk;
    int lenToBeRead = 0x1000;
    DWORD nread;
    char* alignedBuf = new char[lenToBeRead];

    fd = CreateFile("path to volume", FILE_READ_DATA,
      FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
      NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL)) //success

    DeviceIoControl(fd, FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO,
      NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &junk, (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL) //success

    ReadFile(fd, alignedBuf, (DWORD) lenToBeRead, &nread, NULL)
     // fails with 0x57 code, ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
```

All work with fd handle is synchronous.

EDIT. I solved the problem. I was trying to read last bytes. So my volume was of length `L = 0x...200` and I had my handle on position `pos = L - 0x200`. What I had done before I did the `FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO` thing - I cut `lenToBeRead` to fit in remaining space (so, if it was 0x1000, it would change to 0x200), because I had found that `ReadFile` did not guarantee read all the bytes to the EOF in case of `lenToBeRead` is greater than amount of bytes remained from current handle position. This did not help, `ReadFile`was still returning with success and 0 bytes read. I deleted that fix and then used `FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO`, which deliver me then `ReadFile` failing with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` on `lenToBeRead` = 0x1000. I totally forgot about the first fix and remembered now and now it works.

Comment: `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` faster of all because `lenToBeRead` or file offset, from which you try read is invalid. however this data you not show

Comment: Are you certain the sector you're trying to read actually exists?  What happens when you try to read the same sector from the physical drive rather than the logical volume?

Comment: @RbMm that was it. I forgot to cut `lenToBeRead` to fit in remaining space. I have editted my question to add this data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and add it to the question body.
What one has to keep in mind when working with `ReadFile` is to control arguments (length) to not cross the boundary of the file.
I had tried it as a fix before doing the `FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO` thing and it did not help. But combination of the `FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO` thing and the boundary check gave me wanted result - I could read that last bytes.